# Auto-pin the task pane in Outlook on load of add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to set the default value for a pinnable task pane for an add-in to be pinned instead of un-pinned. I am unable to find any mention of this in the docs.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time.

Suggestions for new features can be made at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins